# Access is denied in SharePoint BDC Secure Store Service application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have one serious issue with BCS of SharePoint 2010, If you can help.
I want to use external data (from SQL Server). For that I have configure Business Data Connectivity Service. and also created Secure Store Connection using my credential.

Now, it was working fine & it populate the correct data. but when i tried with different user credential it gives me no result with correlation id.

I checked that using ULVLog & it says 
The Microsoft Secure Store Service application Secure Store Service failed to retrieve credentials. The error returned was 'Access is denied.'. For more information, see the Microsoft SharePoint Products and Technologies Software Development Kit (SDK).

Now, I have given all most all the permission to this user like from the Database level i have given him admin rights on that database. In Secure Store I have given him full permission. In BDC Service Object I have added him with full access. In that SharePoint site i have added him in admin Group. still don't know why it gives me same ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single account to be used for BCS Connection and not give permissions to all the users then you can use [RevertToSelf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802753%28v=office.14%29.aspx) Authentication Mode for BCS Service Application as described in [SP 2010: BCS problem with AuthenticationMode and RevertToSelf](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-bcs-problem-with-authenticationmode-and-reverttoself)

About the permission changes not taking place, try resetting IIS or restarting Timer Service!

Comment: I checked the same mentioned in this link.. but still getting an error
Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

correlation ID also gives me the same The error returned was 'Access is denied.'

Answer (score 0):

Having this issue - made the change to Administrators for the secure store as described here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimmiet/archive/2012/07/04/10326828.aspx

BUT - still didn't work until I restarted the Timer Service.

Be sure to try that too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the user as a "member" not as an "administrator" of the target application. This can only be done when you create the target app unfortunately. Also set it to Group.

Answer (score -2):

Enabling Anonymous Access to a BCS External List

http://sharepoint.mindsharpblogs.com/pauls/Lists/Categories/Category.aspx?Name=SharePoint%20Designer%202010

Comment: He doesn't want anonymous access on External List

Comment: Expose all business data to everyone just to make it work? Umm, no.